# Creating reusable web components for a single page in Vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, html-table, web-component

I have a HTML page that creates a table using jQuery to get my data and vanilla JavaScript to create the table. I wanted to create a class for my set table creation method, so that I could export it and reuse it throughout the HTML code. Am I on the right track here?

Current table creation code

```
function(data) {
                //Rename the variable so I can reuse some code 
                var data_list = data.dataList;
                //Headers for our tables second row
                var titles = data.headers;
                //HTML table variables
                var perRow = 2, html = "<table><tr>";
                //Loop through our array of data
                for (var i = 0; i < data_list.length; i++) {
                    //Add our header first, as we want that to appear first
                    html += "<td>" + titles[i]+ "</td>";
                    //Then add the correct data piece for the header
                    html += "<td>" + data_list[i]+ "</td>";
                    //Break into the next row
                    var next = i+1;
                    if (next % perRow == 0 && next != data_list.length) {
                        //Start new row
                        html += "</tr><tr>";
                    }
                }
                //End the table
                html += "</tr><table>";
                //Attach the table to the HTML doc when finished
                document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = html;
            };
```

What I was thinking it would look like in another .js file

```
class dataTable extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();

        //Get our data
        this.dataList = data.dataList;
        this.dataHeaders = data.headers;

        //HTML attribute for creating our table
        this.html = "<table><tr>";
    }

    createTable() {
        //Items we want per roq
        var perRow = 2;

        //Loop through our data
        for (var i = 0; i < this.dataList; i++) {
            //Add our headers first
            this.html += "<td>" + this.dataHeaders[i] + "</td>";
            //Then add the corresponding piece of data
            this.html += "<td>" + this.dataList[i] + "</td>";
            //Decide when to break into the next row
            var next = i+1;

            if (next % perRow == 0 && next != this.dataList.length) {
                //Add the end row HTML
                this. html += "</tr><tr>"
            }
        }
        //End the table
        this.html += "</tr><table>";

        document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = this.html;
    }
}
```

Am I on the right track? Should I just use a function? Would this class work correctly if I included its .js file in the same directory? I just want to use some OOP principles to make my own web components before I learn a framework.

Comment: You are on the right track. But as far as I know `class` and `extends` are not part of Vanilla Javascript and most of the browser's won't support it. You have to create the javascript using `class` and `extends` and then compile it using webpack to convert it to vanilla javascript.

Comment: @KaleshKaladharan Yeah the video I watched didn’t use export, they just saved it as a separate .js file and imported it. Thanks

Comment: Probably they transpiled the ES6 js files and imported the generated plain javascript file.

Comment: [`class` is certainly part of vanilla JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class), as is [`extends`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends). Extending `HTMLElement` is a different topic: [Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components), which are a group of standards, not all of which are widely supported.

Comment: Noted. Thanks @HereticMonkey . Do you know where I could learn about extending it?

Comment: I (in person) think that this type of questions should be posted in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ymz apologies. Thank you

Comment: Please read their help center first before posting on [codereview.se].

Comment: Heretic Monkey is correct. `class` is very well supported, Web Components less so, and is pretty complex too.  Best course is perhaps to write a jQuery plugin (also called a component) or a [jQuery UI Widget](https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/).

Comment: @Sheepy didn’t even know jQuery had UI widgets. I only have it for an Ajax call. Thanks!

Comment: @RobertSmith subclassing with extend at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Sub_classing_with_extends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally there should be a shadowRoot with a slot for the element's html, otherwise it's possible to insert the table into the shadowRoot. This example will target the HTML via a slot:

in the HTML (static page, or whatever) include this: `<data-grid>data-grid</data-grid>`

in the loaded module, via import or script type=module:

```
/*
this is an example to show basics, it's not ideal, however it answers the question with a working example
*/
class DataTable extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        // static, or request, or setup default and update later...
        this.dataList = [[1,2], [7,9]];
        this.dataHeaders = ['one', 'two'];

        // only work with shadowRoot in constructor, never the HTML element
        // minimize work here too, do that later in lifecycle callbacks
        this.attachShadow({mode:'open'}).innerHTML = `
<!-- NOTE how this th styling doesn't work because the table is rendered into the HTML, not the shadowRoot -->
<style>
/* styles shadow content in the host */
:host th{text-align:left;color:blue;}
/* only top-level selectors */
::slotted(table){text-align:right;}
</style>
<table style="width:100%;"><tr><th>ok</th></tr></table>
<button>update table</button>
<slot></slot>
        `;
        this.shadowRoot.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', this.updateTable.bind(this));
    }
    connectedCallback(){
    // change attributes, html, etc here
        this.createTable();
    }
    random(){
        const max=Date.now();
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
    }
    updateTable(){
        this.dataList = this.dataList.map((row, i)=>{
            return row.map(this.random);
        });
        this.createTable();
    }
    createTable() {
        // use the render cycle
        cancelAnimationFrame(this._createTable);
        this._createTable = requestAnimationFrame(()=>{
        // html will go into the shadowRoot slot (default or whatever is targeted)
        this.innerHTML = `
<table>
<thead><tr>
    ${ this.dataHeaders.reduce((html, col, i)=>{
        return html + `<th>${i+1} ${col}</th>`;
    }, '') }
</tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr>${ this.dataList.map((row, i)=>{
    return `<td>${ row.join('</td><td>') }</td>`;
}).join('</tr><tr>') }</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
        `;
        });
    }
}
// define the element, if not already
customElements.get('data-grid') || customElements.define('data-grid', DataTable);
```

See a working [example](https://jimmont.github.io/demos/web-component/) ([commit](https://github.com/jimmont/demos/commit/ae839ce53970bca67eba706cb25a8658c1bfc6cc)) and the Google Web Developer docs for [Web Components best-practices](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/best-practices).